# CreateAPIView with Empty Serializer (no field)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing 'Follow' CreateAPIView.

FollowCreateAPIView 
- gets 'logged-in User' from self.request.user
- gets 'user's **id**' who 'Logged-in User' wants to follow (from url)
- with the information above, Follow create new data!

Here is urls.py

```
url(r'^follow/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', FollowCreateAPIView.as_view(), name="user_profile"),
```

Model

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='follower')
    following = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='following')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

CreateAPIView (I can't get user_id from URL; `print(following_id)` returns `None`
)

```
class FollowCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Follow.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FollowCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        following_id = self.request.GET.get('user_id', None)
        print(following_id) <<<<- HERE!
        following_user = User.objects.filter(id=following_id)
        serializer.save(follower=self.request.user, following=following_user)
```

Serializer

```
class FollowCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ()
```

- Could you fix this problem? And this `Like` feature seems very common. **Do you have any better approach?** (if you have...)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check out the Update views of DRF. I'm sure there is code that already does what you need - use the ID in the URL to get a model instance or return 404 in case it is not found. You could customize the remaining logic in a subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get the value with kwargs. Also, you can use get instead of filter as `id` is incremental and unique.

```
try:
    following_user = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['user_id'])
except User.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

Thanks Risadinha for pointing that out.

Comment: You can use `filter()` just fine. Depends on whether you want to catch `DoesNotExist` (`get()`) errors or just check for `None` or `exists()` (`filter()`).

Comment: In this case, if `user_id` is not found, you should `raise Http404` - this would be the correct behavior.